# Spring security: New user workflow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring security.

I have created a custom form that logs a user in and then, upon successful login, the user continues to his/her intended webpage. My implementation is standard and it works.

Here's my problem.

- A user wants to go to page *mywebpage.html*.
- The user is not logged in.  The
  user is redirected (by Spring Security) to the login page.
- The user
  does not have an account.
- The user clicks on the createAccount link
  and goes via standard MVC protocols to a registration page.

***How do I now get the user's originally intended destination (mywebpage.html) from Spring Security, so I can redirect the user to that page once he/she has created an account?***

For the record, security.xml

```html
 <http auto-config="true">

 <intercept-url pattern="/login"  access="permitAll()" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/flow-entry.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>


  <form-login
         login-page="/login"
         authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
 
      <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

login form

```html
   <form name='f' action="login" method='POST'>
      <table style="text-align:left" class="w3-table" >
      <tr style="text-align:center;color:red" th:if="${loginresponse}">
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" th:text="#{${loginresponse}}">  </td>

         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td th:text="#{label.emaillogin}"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" value=''/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td th:text="#{label.password}">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-hover-aqua w3-round-large" th:value="#{label.ok}" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/> 
         </tr>
         <tr style="text-align:center">
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">  <a href="./register"><span th:text="#{label.register}"></span></a> </td>

         </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

***Controller Method. I need originally intended web page in this method***

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/doRegistration", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doRegistration(ModelAndView mv, HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    mv.setViewName("register");
    SSm.getLogger().debug("registering new user");
    String email = request.getParameter("username");
    String email1 = request.getParameter("username1");
    if(email.equals(email1))
    {
        if(email.contains("@")&&email.contains("."))
        {
            SSm.getLogger().debug("got legit email");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
            if(password.equals(password1))
            {
                SSm.getLogger().debug("ready to login");

         I NEED USERS ORIGINALLY INTENDED DESTINATION RIGHT HERE SO I CAN SET THE VIEW

            }
            else
            {
                mv.setViewName("register");
                mv.addObject("loginresponse", "message.passwordmismatch");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mv.setViewName("register");
            mv.addObject("loginresponse", "message.invalidemail");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mv.setViewName("register");
        mv.addObject("loginresponse", "message.emailmismatch");
    }


    return mv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).

When a non authorized request reaches the [ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html), a [RequestCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/RequestCache.html) of class [HttpSessionRequestCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/HttpSessionRequestCache.html) is created and the original request is saved on it.

This way, if you do not set `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` to true, httpRequest would be reconstructed and used as target url while correct login is performed.

So, try to @Autowire (I use @Resource instead as I have more than one AuthenticationManager and AuthenticationSuccessHandler in my security config) the AuthenticationSuccessHandler in your controller and calling `determineTargetUrl()` like this:

I made a little modifications such as use `@Valid` annotations and implement a `Validator` to validate the registration form

Security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="savedRequestSuccesHandler" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/zone4/secured/securedPage.htm" />   
</beans:bean>

<security:http pattern="/zone4/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="mainAuthenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/zone4/simple/**"  access="permitAll()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/zone4/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/zone4/simple/login.htm" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="savedRequestSuccesHandler" 
        username-parameter="email" 
        password-parameter="password"
        login-processing-url="/zone4/secured/performLogin.htm" 
    />
    <security:logout 
        logout-url="/zone4/secured/performLogout.htm" 
        logout-success-url="/zone4/simple/login.htm" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.eej.ssba2.controller.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.eej.ssba2.model.test.zone4.RegisterModel;
import com.eej.ssba2.model.test.zone4.RegisterModelValidator;

/**
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/zone4")
public class Zone4TestController {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Resource(name="mainAuthenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Resource(name="savedRequestSuccesHandler")
    private SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @RequestMapping("/simple/unsecuredPage.htm")
    public String unsecuredPage(){
        return "simple/unsecuredPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/secured/securedPage.htm")
    public String securedPage1(){
        return "simple/secured/securedPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/secured/securedPage2.htm")
    public String securedPage2(){
        return "simple/secured/securedPage2";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/secured/securedPage3.htm")
    public String securedPage3(){
        return "simple/secured/securedPage3";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/simple/login.htm")
    public String login(){
        return "simple/login/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/simple/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(ModelMap model){
        logger.debug("Entrada en register.htm");
        if(!model.containsAttribute("registerModel")){
            model.addAttribute("registerModel", new RegisterModel());
        }
        return "simple/login/register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/simple/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            @Valid RegisterModel registerModel, ModelMap model, BindingResult bindingResult){
        logger.info("entrada en register");
        RegisterModelValidator userValidator = new RegisterModelValidator();
        userValidator.validate(registerModel, bindingResult);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            logger.info("BindingResult has errors: " + bindingResult.getAllErrors());
            model.addAttribute("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
            model.addAttribute("registerModel", registerModel);
            return "simple/login/register";

        }

        // Your user register business

        Authentication authenticated = null;
        /*
         * If the user is created at this time due to your business logic, you could authenticate it directly 
         * through the manager
         *
        authenticated = 
                this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            registerModel.getMail1(), 
                            registerModel.getPassword1()                        
                        )
                );
        */
        authenticated = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    registerModel.getMail1(), 
                    registerModel.getPassword1(), 
                    Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))
                );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticated);
        try {
            this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authenticated);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Registration model bean:

```
package com.eej.ssba2.model.test.zone4;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.eej.ssba2.ApplicationVersion;

/**
 * 
 *
 */
public class RegisterModel implements Serializable{

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*" +
            "@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$|")
    public String mail1;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*" +
            "@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$|")
    public String mail2;

    @NotEmpty
    public String password1;

    @NotEmpty
    public String password2;

    // getters and setters  

}
```

The Validator imiplementation I use to validate the fields in the model:

```
package com.eej.ssba2.model.test.zone4;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

    public class RegisterModelValidator implements Validator {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
            return RegisterModel.class.equals(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
            RegisterModel user = (RegisterModel) target;
            if(!user.getMail1().equals(user.getMail2())){
                errors.rejectValue("mail1", "lbl_mail1_and_mail2_must_be_equal");
                errors.rejectValue("mail2", "lbl_mail1_and_mail2_must_be_equal");
            }
            if(!user.getPassword1().equals(user.getPassword2())){
                errors.rejectValue("password1", "lbl_pass1_and_pass2_must_be_equal");
                errors.rejectValue("password2", "lbl_pass1_and_pass2_must_be_equal");
            }
        }
```

Finally, the registration jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form role="registerModel" commandName="registerModel" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/zone4/simple/register.htm">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:input path="mail1" id="mail1" name="mail1" placeHolder="email" />
                <form:errors path="mail1" id="mail1" name="mail1" placeHolder="email" cssClass="error" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:input path="mail2" id="mail2" name="mail2" placeHolder="email" />
                <form:errors path="mail2" id="mail2" name="mail2" placeHolder="email" cssClass="error" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:input path="password1" id="password1" name="password1" placeHolder="password" />
                <form:errors path="password1" id="password1" name="password1" placeHolder="password" cssClass="error" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:input path="password2" id="password2" name="password2" placeHolder="password" />
                <form:errors path="password2" id="password2" name="password2" placeHolder="password" cssClass="error" />                
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="remember-me" id="remember-me" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" name="submit"><spring:message code="lblRegistration"/></button>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: really helpful. I'll work on it today, tomorrow and upvote when verified. Just want you to know I've read it and appreciate your input